# Unlimited tweet search using java

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have a requirement for retrieving all(i mean "all") till a given date or between dates.
But the code i wrote gives me tweets but only for today. I implemented paging but its no help i do get multiple pages and the data is not redundant. But the data is still limited for the current day. I only get like 600-700 tweets. And i used hasNext() and it retrieves false after 6-7 pages. 
I'm fairly new to this API and i dont have much idea about the framework so forgive me if i sound really naive.

Heres the code:

```
Query search=new Query(searchKeyWord);
    QueryResult results;
    search.setCount(100);
    //search.setMaxId(-1);
    search.setSince("2013-01-01");
    search.lang("en");
//  search.setUntil("2013-05-01");
    int i=0;
    //TwitterFactory.getSingleton().search(search);//
    do{
        i++;
        System.out.println("Page "+i);
        results=tweety.search(search);

    for(Status stats : results.getTweets()){

    Text=stats.getText();
    Text=Text.replace("\n", " ");
    writer.append(stats.getUser().getScreenName()+";"+Text+";"+stats.getCreatedAt()+";"+"\n");  

    }

    search=results.nextQuery();


    } while(search!=null);
```

The requirement is for text mining on a large amount data so the more tweets retrieved the better. Of course I will restricting the since and until dates. But if i set the dates for an older time interval the tweets are still retrieved only for the last day of that interval.

Am i wrong here somewhere? And is there something I need to add or change to get all the tweets? I'm aware of rate limits. Is this the reason why i receive only limited data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use both search API and Streaming API. I am also working on data mining with twitter data and what I am doing is I just implemented two different apps to collect tweets. You can also do same thing. The streaming API needs only one twitter account for token and authentication stuff.However, you should have more accounts for the search API. If you have more questions let me know.

Comment: Hey thanks. I thought i'd use the same method too. But the thing is the kind of keywords we will use is going to filter out the tweets by applying a lot of context restrictions. So we won't be receiving a continous flow of data which means we're just wasting time on a persistent connection. 
We need atleast a bag full of data to conduct the analysis like 10000 to 1000000 tweets. Which isn't possible. Somehow twitter restricts the data you receive by count and also by date. That means  you can only search for tweets few days before current date.

Comment: I thought i'd use the same search api program everyday to collect data over a period of time. So that we catch some experimental data until we get special access rights from twitter maybe. Btw does twitter provide any rights?